# Sublime Syntax Regex Only Highlight Match Within Delimiters

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I would like to match a string with regular expressions that occurs within specified delimiters, but **not** the delimiters themselves, for the purpose of syntax highlighting in a Sublime Text package. I am running ST3.

For example, from the [sublime-notes](https://github.com/tbh1/sublime-notes) package, this `<dict>` element is used to match text between `<` and `>`, **including** the angle brackets themselves, which leads to `<this>` being highlighted, instead of just <`this`>.

```
<dict>
    <key>comment</key>
    <string>Important, surrounded by &lt;...&gt;</string>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>(\&lt;[^\&gt;]*\&gt;)</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>constant.other.date.notes</string>
</dict>
```

How can I modify the regex between the `<string>` tags to not include the elbow brackets in the syntax highlighting?

Comment: Try `<string>&lt;([\s\S]*?)&gt;</string>` or `<string>(?<=&lt;)([\s\S]*?)(?=&gt;)</string>`.

Comment: The first suggestion didn't work, but the second one gets halfway there! The XML doesn't like the `<` you have in the first group there. I removed the `<`, and the result is that the **right angle bracket** is not highlighted (what I want), but the left angle bracket is still highlighted. In other words, it's giving me `<this`>

Comment: I see your idea though with the lookbehind, the issue is that the regular expression can't be wrapped in quotes, and the XML thinks `<` is the beginning of a new tag. Is there a way to get around using the lookbehind first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put the left and right delimiters inside lookaround constructs:

```
<string>(?&lt;=&lt;)([^&gt;]*)(?=&gt;)</string>
```

Or, using CDATA block to avoid serializing special XML chars:

```
<string><![CDATA[(?<=<)([^>]*)(?=>)]]></string>
```

The pattern will look like `(?<=<)([^>]*)(?=>)` after the XML parser deserializes the pattern string, and `(?<=<)` will match a location that is immediately preceded with `<` char, while `(?=>)` positive lookahead will assure the next char is `>` (or the match will fail).

Comment: This works perfectly, and very creative! Thank you very much.

Comment: @tsouchlarakis Well, it is not that creative, I was just baffled by the `[^\&gt;]` that does not make sense in the literal string pattern and looks misleading. Once I realized it is part of XML, it became clear. Actually, you might as well - and it is better - use a CDATA block: `<string><![CDATA[(?<=<)([^>]*)(?=>)]]></string>`

Comment: This works, and I just implemented it. Thank you again. Can you walk me through why it's better to use a CDATA block?

Comment: @tsouchlarakis You do not need to serialize `<`, `>` and `&`.